# Rename method of Ruby; escaping colon

Tags: ruby, file, file-rename

How do you escape a colon, when renaming files in Ruby?

I have following code (names is a hash with data already filled in):

```
new_filename = ""
counter = 0 
Dir.glob(folder_path + "/*").each do |f|
  numbering = names.index(names.values.sort[counter])
  new_filename = numbering + " - " + names.values.sort[counter]
  puts "New file name: " + new_filename
  File.rename(f, folder_path + "/" + new_filename + File.extname(f))
  counter += 1
end

puts "Renaming complete."
```

The output of `new_filename` is correct, e.g. `"Foo - Bar: Foo.txt"`. When it renames the file, the file has following format: `"Foo - Bar/ Foo.txt"`.

I tried escaping with the colon with a backslash, but doesn't seem to work, because my output then looks like this: `"Foo - Bar/\ Foo.txt"`.

Is is possible to have a colon in a string for renaming files?

Comment: Which system do you use? Windows does not allow `:` in filenames. Some OS (I think Mac) use `:` as separator for folders. It seems Ruby interpret the `:` as a new folder.

Comment: @knut: Old MacOS used `:` for folders, OSX uses `/` like other flavors of Unix. A filename with a colon is displayed as-is in the shell but Finder converts the colon to a slash for display purposes.

Comment: @muistooshort: Technically, I'm pretty sure ":" is still used as the separator in HFS+ — IIRC, it's swapped with "/" at the POSIX level (because that's the POSIX separator), and then the GUI layer swaps them back.

Comment: @Chuck: Cool, thanks. I wasn't sure how POSIXified things were. The underlying lesson remains: don't try to use slashes or colons in file names.

Comment: Yes, I'm running OSX. So I guess colon is not possible at all. Oh well... then I got to use another symbol.

Answer (score 0):

FYI - in NTFS a colon identifies a separate stream of the same file... "Foo Bar: Foo.txt" identifies file "Foo Bar", stream " Foo.txt". Reference "Alternate Data Streams" (currently http://support.microsoft.com/kb/105763). AFIK this feature is not really widely used, though I have seen it used to tag files with thrid-party data (I use it to store a file's sha1 for dupe identification under the stream *:sha1).