# rsync get from mac to linux: colon replacement

Tags: linux, macos, bash, rsync

I'm backing up on a linux to rsync data from a remote apple mac to save locally.

linux/mac use "/" or ":" to define path hierarchy,
so if mac filenames contain a "/", then rsync replaces the "/" with a ":" to stay safe.

however, sharing/networking this backup back to mac causes troubles this way.

**Is there a way I can tell rsync to take another character, ie "_"?**

I could rename my files using

```
find /path/to/basedir/* -iname "*:*"  | tac |  sed 's/\(.*\):\(.*\)$/mv "&" "\1_\2"/' | sh
```

but this breaks the rsync incremental magic.

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It isn't rsync doing the translation; it's done by the kernel and filesystem APIs (see [this previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13298434/colon-appears-as-forward-slash-when-creating-file-name) and [the linked USENIX paper](http://www.wsanchez.net/papers/USENIX_2000/)). The tricky character appears as a slash in MacOS-heritage APIs, and as a colon in unix-heritage APIs; rsync uses unix-heritage APIs, so it sees a colon.

The best solution isn't to try to translate the character differently, it's to figure out what's going wrong with the sharing/networking you're using, and figure out why it *isn't* doing the appropriate translation.

Comment: Thanks, good approach. It turned out I could solve the problem by rechecking same versions of rsync and upgrade netatalk. M