# Chrome/FF file upload replaces file name containing "/" with ":"

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome, firefox, file-upload

Chrome/FF seems to be replacing "/" character in the file name with ":".

Steps to reproduce:

1. Hit [this page](http://nervgh.github.io/pages/angular-file-upload/examples/simple/)
2. Select a file name with "/" character in it
3. Check the file name being shown on the webpage. It will have the "/"
   replaced with ":"

I have scoured the web for an explanation on this behaviour but cant seem to find anything article on specifically this behaviour.

I understand the fakepath behaviour is required as a security measure, and that this may be a logical extension of the same. But where is this specific behaviour defined?

Comment: Its on firefox too. I sit corrected!

Comment: emm - [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13298434/colon-appears-as-forward-slash-when-creating-file-name)? You should check out the comments.

Comment: Thank you! Apparently I was searching for "fileupload '/' replaced with ':' " and was hitting all sorts of fakepath problems, should've just tried the english equivalents of those symbols instead in my searches..

Comment: Nice. Little trick to know for future. :D