# Formatting timestamp in bash for use in a file operation

Tags: bash, date, timestamp, cp

I'm getting some strangeness from bash when I try to use a timestamp as part of a filename.

```
#!/bin/bash

DATE=`date -d "today" +"%Y%m%d-%H:%M"`
dtl=$DATE.log

for drive in $( ls /dev/disk/by-id | grep 'scsi-35' ); do
  mkdir -p /home/tt/drivelog/${drive}
  cp /home/tt/drivelog/currentset/$drive.log "/home/tt/drivelog/$drive/$dtl"
done
```

1. The above results in a file named 20171122-12/15.log, so my comma has turned into a forward slash = not what I want.
2. I tried (to no avail) escaping out the colon by using:

   DATE=`date -d "today" +"%Y%m%d-%H\:%M"`

   which results in a file named 20171122-12\/15.log
3. I use double quotes to ensure there was no ambiguity in the reference, which can happen with colons in filenames.  Didn't fix.
4. When I try some debugging and just echo the source and destination portions of the cp command, it looks *right*.  But that normality disappears when I join them together in the cp command.  Echo output:

   `/home/tt/drivelog/currentset/scsi-35000c50094vv123z.log
   /home/tt/drivelog/scsi-35000c50094vv123z/20171122-11:55.log`
5. Lastly, substituting .../${drive}/${dtl}" doesn't fix it...

Many thanks! (Image below, showing recent results)

[image: cosmic rays aren't making this happen]

for John1024:
I made sure date was working, output from date cmd:

`20171122-12:47`

and as reported in bash:

`+ dtl=20171122-12:50.log`

Using bash to run the script highlighted the issue:
1.  The command is working properly...

`+ cp /home/tt/drivelog/currentset/scsi-35000c50094aa123z.log /home/tt/drivelog/scsi-35000c50094aa123z/20171122-12:50.log`

2. The issue is that the Mac on which I am looking at the folder is not showing the output properly.

ls in the output directory shows:

`20171122-11:58.log
20171122-12\:00.log
20171122-12\:27.log
20171122-12\:48.log
20171122-12:50.log`

Yet the view of this from my Mac drops the colon

[image]

I'm going to mark this as closed, as the underlying issue is a Mac AFP display incongruity issue, and not a bash issue.  See: [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13298434/colon-appears-as-forward-slash-when-creating-file-name)  Mac OS used colons as path separators when I first started using them in 1984.  With the move to OS X, now eons ago, that changed. AFP and third-party implementations of AFP come with "YMMV" caveats, and this is apparently one I missed.

Many thanks to John1024

Comment: Run `date -d "today" +"%Y%m%d-%H:%M"` at the command line all by itself and tell us what you see.  Next, run `bash -x yourscript` and show us the results.

Comment: @John1024, if you would please give an answer with  "I think this is a Mac APFS display incongruity issue," I will accept that answer and we can close this out.   Thanks.

Comment: You did good work and you solved it.  It is perfectly good form on StackOverflow to write an answer to your own question and accept it.

Comment: As documentation: ["Yes! Stack Exchange has always explicitly encouraged users to answer their own questions."](https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer)

Comment: APFS is not really relevant here, it's due to an inconsistency in macOS's APIs. Some use unix path notation (with "/" as a directory delimiter and ":" allowed in filenames) and some use the old Mac OS notation (with ":" as a delimiter and "/" allowed in filenames). So what character that is in the filename depends on which API is used to access (/list) it, not what type of volume it's on.

Answer (score 1):

The issue here is that the underlying colon is not showing properly over AFP.

The code above does, actually, generate colons as intended.  See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13298434/colon-appears-as-forward-slash-when-creating-file-name) for more on the idiosyncrasies of OS X (and prior versions).