# How can I make this OneDrive sanitiser work?

Tags: regex, perl

I'm learning to code, following tutorials to try and fix a problem that's been annoying - to clean up files on macOS so they don't jam OneDrive from working.

I have followed several tutorials and it's very nearly doing what I'd hope.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -w
use strict;
use warnings;
use File::Find;

my @argv;
my $dir = $ARGV[0];

find(\&dirRecurs, $dir);

sub dirRecurs{

    if (-f and not 's/^\./' )
    {
        (my $txt = $_) =~ s/^\ | (?=\.)|[\/!#%^?*&()\\]| $//g;
        rename($_, $txt);
    }

}
```

I expected it to exclude `.dotfiles` from the renaming process as a result of `and not 's/^\./'` but it doesn't.  If I remove the `and not 's/^\./'` from the if line, all works as I'd hope, except

I expected `\/` in the regex to rename files like `more/less.pdf` but it doesn't

Comment: please clarify: is `more/less.pdf` the name of a file or is it the path to a file (`less.pdf` inside directory `more`) ?

Comment: `more/less.pdf` is the filename.  I'm amazed that MS Office will let you call a file a name with a slash in it.  The substitution regex won't pick up these slashes.  The `-f` in the `if` makes sure that there are no path slashes.

Comment: actually, the `-f` ensures you don't rename directories (which presumably could contain slashes and other odd characters too).

Comment: don't know if this command will work on a mac but what type of fs is this file on: `mount | fgrep $(realpath "$(df  more/less.pdf | awk 'NR==2{print $1}')")`

Comment: Sorry, I'm not sure how to answer that!  It's MacOS.  What finder shows as `more/less.pdf` appears as `more:less.pdf` in terminal `ls`.  This is really puzzling me.  The files with the forward slash are being created on Windows 7 and Windows 10 or Mac.  They come from MS Office applications.

Comment: [link]https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13298434/colon-appears-as-forward-slash-when-creating-file-name[/link] explains that `/` is really a `:` but finder shows it the wrong way.  So I'll remove colons from the names.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The line of code in question is:

```
if (-f and not 's/^\./' )
```

- This succeeds when `-f` is true and `'s/^\./'` is false

  - `-f` tests if `$_` is a file
  - In a boolean context, `'s/^\./'` tests if the given string is not null

Clearly any string that has some characters in it is not null, and so the `if` test always fails.

Looking at the contents of the string, it is clear that the intention was to insert a regular expression test. The one that is required is the `m//` form ("match"). The one that has been (almost) provided, is a malformed version of `s///` (search and replace).

In Perl, regular expressions generally do not appear as strings. The appropriate form is (`m` is optional):

```
if (-f and not m/^\./)
```

---

As couple of asides:

- `@argv` is not used in your code (and is not the same as `@ARGV`)
- use `find(\&dirRecurs, @ARGV);` to search more than one path (provided as arguments to the perl script)
- You perform rename even if there has been no change. This can be prevented by wrapping in and `if`:

```
if ((my $txt = $_) =~ s/^\ | (?=\.)|[\/!#%^?*&()\\]| $//g) {
    rename($_, $txt);
}

# or:

rename($_, $txt)
    if (my $txt = $_) =~ s/^\ | (?=\.)|[\/!#%^?*&()\\]| $//g;
```

Comment: Thank you so much, this is a brilliant explanation and is really helpful.

Comment: one other check would be to ensure the new name doesn't clobber an existing file

Comment: Good call - thank you.  Just tried it: in such a case it deletes the file that's being renamed.  So it needs `rename -> tempname -> check against existing files -> if clash append incremental to tempname -> go ahead and rename`.  That's my next puzzle.